# C++11 for loop syntax not working properly

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, foreach

I'm making an Arkanoid clone using SFML as a learning exercise. For the PowerUp class, I have an update method like this:

```
void PowerUp::update(FrameTime mFT) {
  if (!(bottom() >= windowHeight))
    shape.move(velocity * mFT);
  else
    onGround = true;
}
```

In my PowerUpManager class, I have a PowerUp vector, and this function to update all PowerUp's at once:

```
void PowerUpManager::update(FrameTime mFT) {
  for (auto powerUp : mPowerUps)
    powerUp.update(mFT);
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. If I run this code, the powerups just stay still after spawning and do not move downwards, like they should. However, if I replace

```
for (auto powerUp : mPowerUps)
  powerUp.update(mFT);
```

with the more traditional but older fashioned

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < mPowerUps.size(); ++i)
  mPowerUps[i].update(mFT);
```

, everything works fine and as it should. This tells me that there is a difference in the meaning of those 2 bits of code. As far as I was aware, the former was simply the new C++ syntactic sugar version of the latter. Is there something I'm missing?

What's even stranger is that my draw all function,

```
void PowerUpManager::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
  for (auto powerUp : mPowerUps)
    powerUp.draw(window);
}
```

, works fine and with no issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that in the loop `powerUp` is a *copy* from the `mPowerUps` container. You need to use references:

```
for (auto& powerUp : mPowerUps)
    powerUp.update(mFT);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple that it flew right past my head. As a follow up question, does my current version of the draw function (without a reference) add unnecessary overhead by essentially copying the object and then drawing it?

Comment: @Bluejay Yes, copying will always add some extra overhead, as it involves calling the copy-constructor. As a common way of handling and implementing references is by using pointers, the overhead of using references is the same as copying a pointer: A four or eight byte copy of the pointer and no function calls, generally much less overhead than object copying.